# Sass dynamic styles to avoid repetition

Tags: sass

I have a dynamic angular directive that creates the image paths based on some conditions.

```
scope.image = 'myImage-test-'+imageIndex; //image index is a random num between 1-5
```

in my directive template,

In my scss file, I have the following styles added to map these images

```
   .container {
       &--myImage-test-1 {
            background: url(../images/image-1.jpg); 
       }
       &--myImage-test-2 {
            background: url(../images/image-2.jpg); 
       }
       &--myImage-test-3 {
            background: url(../images/image-3.jpg); 
       }
       &--myImage-test-4 {
            background: url(../images/image-4.jpg); 
       }
       &--myImage-test-5 {
            background: url(../images/image-5.jpg); 
       }
    }
```

I am planning to increase the count of my image to 50  and I don't like to hardcode styles for all these 50 images, which is lot of repetition. Would like to know if there is a possibility of abetter alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple with sass. You just need a for loop.

```
.container {
   //for loop 1-50 
   @for $i from 1 through 50 {
      &--myImage-test-#{$i} {
         background: url(../images/image-#{$i}.jpg); 
   }
}
```